# What is the canonical way to simulate grouped targets in older versions of Make?

Tags: makefile

What is the best way to simulate Make's [grouped targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Multiple-Targets.html#Rules-with-Grouped-Targets) feature for older versions of Make that do not have the feature?

**UPDATE**

It looks like a [static pattern rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Static-Usage) might work:

> "Pattern rules are always treated as grouped targets ... regardless of whether they use the : or &: separator"

Comment: Where are you finding versions of make without support for grouped targets? I feel like those have been around forever. Or are these non-GNU versions of `make`?

Comment: GNU Make v3.0 is on my new Mac, it looks like v4.3 is the one with grouped targets: https://linuxreviews.org/GNU_make_4.3_Is_Released

Answer (score 1):

Grouped targets for pattern rules have been around forever (you don't need `&:` for that, it's the default way they work).  Grouped targets with `&:` for non-pattern rules was introduced in GNU make 4.3 which was released in Jan 2020.

There is no GNU make 3.0.  If you have the default GNU make on MacOS you have something like GNU make 3.81 or something like that.  You'll never get a newer version because Apple will never add a version of GNU software that is under GPLv3 so on MacOS you're stuck with old bash, old make, etc. etc.  You can use homebrew or macports to install newer versions on your own of course (or build them yourself).

Using static pattern rules won't work.  The naming is unfortunate but static pattern rules are actually just a shortcut for writing explicit rules, not pattern rules, and they don't support grouped targets.

If you can't use real pattern rules (your outputs and inputs are not related through some common portion of their filenames) and you can't use GNU make 4.3, then you can use this idiom; if your rule is like this:

```
t1 t2 t3 ... : p1 p2 p3 ...
        command that builds all of t1 t2 t3 ...
```

then you can change it to this:

```
t1 t2 t3 ... : .sentinel ;

.sentinel: p1 p2 p3 ...
        command that builds all of t1 t2 t3 ...
        @touch $@
```

Don't forget the semicolon after the `.sentinel`.  Or if you prefer you can do something like this for that rule: it's equivalent:

```
t1 t2 t3 ... : .sentinel
        @: do nothing
```

(`:` is the shell's "do nothing" operator)  Of course you still need the second rule as well.